# nexmo: Dynamically generate NCCO for outbound call

Tags: node.js, call, vonage

We are using the outbound voice API. We have successfully set up an application and are able to create an outbound call using a test NCCO: https://developer.nexmo.com/ncco/tts.json
We are using the NodeJS SDK.
However, we are not able to understand why the NCCOs must be accessed through URLs, instead of being supplied as a JSON object directly. Moreover, we are using the voice API to verify user accounts at our services. Once a user registers to our services, we give them the option to choose between a SMS or a phonecall to verify their accounts. Evidently, each user will receive a distinct code in their SMS/call (e.g., 1234). We would like to receive help on how to bypass the answer_url field, and be able to supply a distinct text-to-speech text, per user.

In brief, is there a way to, instead of supplying to the voice call API, a static JSON object through a public URL, supply a JSON object dynamically generated that contains a distinct code for the user?

Below is an example of the nexmo node method to generate an outbound call:

`nexmo.calls.create({
    to: [{
        type: 'phone',
        number: RECEIVING_NUMBER
    }],
    from: {
        type: "phone",
        number: NEXMO_VIRTUAL_NUMBER
    },
    answer_url: ['https://developer.nexmo.com/ncco/tts.json']
    }, (err, res) => {
    if(err)  console.log(JSON.stringify(err,null,2)); 
    else { console.log(res); }
})`

Answer (score 2):

You can build Nodejs api that returns JSON and use it as answer_url. by this way you can send query parameters to this api to make dynamic NCCOs.

example:

```js
answer_url: ['https://example.com/answer?code=12345']
```

```js
app.get('/answer', function(req, res) {

  const ncco = [{
      'action': 'talk',
      'voiceName': 'Jennifer',
      'text': req.params.code
    }
  ];
  res.json(ncco);
  
});
```